# storing embed code in mysql from csv

Tags: html, mysql, database, csv, web

I have a very large CSV file containing video embed codes among other inofrmation.

I need to import these embed codes into mysql for retrieval later on, however the column containing the embed codes is being ignored, and all the other columns are being imported with no trouble. How can i get around this and allow the embed codes to be imported too

I really need this to work, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your csv data, and the code you are using to upload the csv....we are coders not wizards :)

Comment: haha of course this is an example of the csv code "<iframe name="examplesite_embed_video" src="http://www.examplesite.com/embed/on-the-red-couch-287123" frameborder="0" width="608" height="490" scrolling="no"></iframe><br /><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/video/on-the-red-couch-287123">On the red couch</a> brought to you by <a href="http://www.examplesite.com/">examplesite.com</a>|On the red couch|tags, go, here the csv is seperated by | and i use this query to import LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/path/to/file' INTO TABLE videos FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: it automatically ignores the embed code and puts the title where the embed code should be!

Comment: Maybe the semicolon close to `287123";` is messing up your upload

Comment: unfortunatley this is not the issue, most records do not have a semicolon, in fact I believe that one was added by mistake

Comment: Maybe if you switch the `""` to `''`

Comment: still didnt solve it, embed codes are ignored as before. I think it may be something to do with all of the html tags, however if i remove tags then the embed codes will be pointless as they wont work

Comment: and if you add this to your options `ESCAPED BY '\\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: The import was not including the first field as it expected to see '|' before the first field!